# How to install a specific version of ruby-dev on termux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, termux

I'm trying to setup ruby on rails environment on termux on android. I want to use `2.1.10 ruby`. All I found was `apt install ruby-dev` or `pkg install ruby-dev` which installs the latest version of ruby. any suggestions?

Comment: I couldn't find anything else either. Have you thought about cross-compiling or compiling in device yourself? https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Package_Management#Cross-compiling_packages

Comment: Here's the Termux Ruby package source: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install rvm.
0. Recomendation: install *tmux* and *zsh*, and change zsh as default shell. *Oh my Zsh* worked. *Powerline* fonts too (by install termux-style script)

Let's install rvm:

1. Install gawk, curl and tar packages:
   `apt install curl gawk tar`
2. Go to rvm.io site  and just copy 'Install RVM' command, look' like:
   `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
3. Add this line `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file
4. Now your shell must writing a syntax PS problem, just open rvm script and edit it:
   `vi ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
   Now you must found a block like:

```
 case "`uname` in
(CYGWIN*|MINGW*)
... etc ...
```

Just replace the 3 initialization variable __shell_name strings with this:

```
__shell_name="gawk 'BEGIN{RS=\"\"}; NR==1{print; exit
}' /proc/$$/cmdline | tr - '\0'" ;;
```

5. Restart shell
6. Now you can install ruby from rvm. Usage at rvm.io
   P.s.: jruby not supported while you don't found solution for install jdk and jre from Termux).
   P.s.: sorry for bad English.

### Update

RVM working with termux: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4734

Comment: I'm getting a parse error near `"$__shell_name"' after editing the rvm script

Answer (score -2):

`apt install ruby-dev` installs ruby 2.5.1-1

And that's the latest version, I think.

Comment: The question is how to install a specific version.